# SQL Inner join using where and order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I have to write a complex searching query with TSQL with many filters and paged them as well as sort them at the same query. I have 2 tables with one to one relations to each other and try to use inner join.

> The first table called **dbo.Products** with following columns: *Id, Name,
>   Price, Model* and *color*.
>
> The second table is called **dbo.Items** with following columns: *Id,
>   products_Id, Tel, Area, Category* and *Date*.

I need to select *Id, Category,Date* and Area from the **Items** table and *Name, Price* and Model from **Products** table. Here is my shot:

```
SELECT Id,Category,Date,Name,Price,Model
FROM dbo.Items
INNER JOIN dbo.Products ON dbo.Items.Id=dbo.Products.Id
WHERE Category=1 AND Name LIKE '%is%' AND Price<1000 AND Area=2
ORDER BY Date DESC
ORDER BY [Id] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

My first question is if the order is correct and the second question is there is better way to write it for better performance, something like using Stored Procedures?

Comment: For a novice like me it is. You are proffessional guyes.

Comment: Not even a complicated query for a novice -- this is covered in the first chapter of any book on SQL.  A join and a where statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax would be:

```
SELECT I.Id,Category,Date,Name,Price,Model
FROM dbo.Items as I
INNER JOIN dbo.Products as P ON I.Id=P.Id
WHERE Category=1 AND Name LIKE '%is%' AND Price<1000 AND Area=2
ORDER BY Date DESC, I.[Id] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: In the first row if my Product table has Date as well I do need to write as following: I.Date?

Comment: Yes, in that case you must explicitly indicate which Date to pick (I or P)

Answer (score 0):

I updated your query based on assumptions on your table structure.  I left the dbo against the tables, though I don't typically query a table with dbo.  it's usually owned by the schema in question.

- Question 1:  You can't run two order by clauses, you would need to comma delimit them by the priority of sorting.
- Question 2: I rewrote the query below.
- Your query also has DEC, which I assume you meant descending (DESC).
- I also merged the two order by clauses into one with a comma ranking
  them.
- I aliased the tables.  This helps ease confusion on what tables you are using and makes it more readable.
- I moved the where clause "where p.Name like '%is%' to the bottom of your where clauses.  This should help speed your query up as you query against indexable and faster filters and reduces the rows that the like will run against.

  ```
  SELECT i.Id,i.Category,i.Date,p.Name,p.Price,p.Model
      FROM dbo.Items i
          INNER JOIN dbo.Products p ON i.Id=p.Id
      WHERE i.Category=1 
          AND p.Price<1000 
          AND i.Area=2
          AND p.Name LIKE '%is%' 
      ORDER BY i.Datum DESC, [i.Id] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
  ```

Comment: I understand that i.Id and p.Id belongs to Items and Products, but in the last row [Id] is not belong to anyone of tables. Is it okey?

Comment: I forgot to highlight that one point.  I can't tell what the relationships of these tables are, but you should join a primary key to a foreign key.  Tables are usually created with ID being the identifier of that row in that table and a foreign key is named relatedTable_id.  In this instance you are joining products to items on product.id=item.id.  Usually it's more like on i.id=p.items_id (if items is the parent).  to see how they are related, look at the tables in sql server mgmt studio, right click the table and select "View Dependencies".  This should show you how they are related.

Comment: No it's not ok.  I updated the sql.  I also assumed Datum is in the items table.  If it belongs to p, then update that.

Comment: Ok, good luck with the SQL!, hope this helped you better understand SQL.